# Index DB, which browser has how much memory capacity?

Tags: browser, web-applications, progressive-web-apps, offline

I try to find an answer to the question IndexDB, which browser (Chrome, EdgeChromium, Firefox, Safari) has how much memory capacity? (target size 1GB).

Can anybody please help me? I am totally new in this topic

Answer (score 0):

It really comes down to how much disk space is available on the device. Most browsers allocate a storage quota to an origin as a percentage of available disk space.
For desktop you should have no problem storing several GB. Most browsers will prompt the user for permission past an initial size. For example 50MB.

Safari can be different. They move quotas a lot. Apple is also aggressive on purging cached data as disk space becomes limited. It does look like you can store as much as 5GB, at least that is the most I have tried.
So always assume the data is missing, or give your app resilience to deal with missing data.